# TFS 2010 store timestamp on status changes

Tags: c#, tfs-workitem

I'm having a request to track time taken for each status change for workitem created in TFS 2010. The plan is to capture the status change event ([something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156090/tfs-execute-custom-code-on-a-work-item-transition)) to store the timestamp when status of the workitem changes, probably in a custom table that has many-to-one relationship with the original workitem. Reporting is done on a custom build ASP.Net dashboard. Is this actually achievable in TFS 2010, and is it recommended? The alternative that I've thought of is using a HTML field and append timestamp to it whenever status changes.

NOTE: I'm quite new to TFS administration, and I've only recently learnt how to configure field definition and rules, though I'm a season C# developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Work Items store history you can actually get the status change timestamp by going through the history, no need to build plugins or anything. The TFS 2010 warehouse already extracts these values into the WorkItemsAre and WorkItemsWere tables.

Comment: Hmm, never thought of that, will give it a try tomorrow when I'm back to office. Thanks!