# Adding a wizard or form to a TFS workitem form to auto create tasks

Tags: tfs

I am working on a project for our group  where when using microsoft TFS and a user creates a workitem a set of tasks needs to be auto created and added to the workitem.  This part I have working.     The hitch is, they want it such that the user can hit a button in the workitem form which will launch a wizard or form or some ui that the user can select which tasks to create or perhaps add others so they can be done in a batch.

This second part is the part I am stumped on.   Has anyone done anything like this? Extending TFS so that a custom form or wizard or what not is kicked off from a button and then tied to a custom extension?

I have tried to search for answers on this and seem to have some potential pieces but nothing putting them together and feeling a bit, well, dumb here.   Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156090/tfs-execute-custom-code-on-a-work-item-transition

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately that is the part I have.  I need to add custom UI on the TFS side.  Something like a button that triggers a custom form/wizard type ui which then sends the data to the server extension I wrote up.  Appreciate it though!  The button I believe is just a custom control - it is spawning UI from it that has me scratching my head.

Comment: Why do you have boiler plate tasks?

Comment: We have some custom workitems which while the content of the work item may differ, there are 3 or 4 tasks that we have come to learn must get done for any of that work item type.   They just want a shortcut way to put them in and an option to pick and choose to accommodate edge cases.